# How to use @SqsListener with multiple object types?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-messaging, spring-cloud-aws

I am trying to migrate some application code from Spring Boot with rabbitmq to Spring Boot with SQS.  I'd like my application to listen to a queue, but handle multiple object types, like this:

```java
    @SqsListener("some-queue")
    public void handleTestModel(TestModel model) {
        LOGGER.info("Received a TestModel.");
    }

    @SqsListener("some-queue")
    public void handleAnotherTestModel(AnotherTestModel model) {
        LOGGER.info("Received AnotherTestModel.");
    }
```

The above code will work, but the methods are picked at random regardless of the contents of the message/JSON shape.  How can I configure my application to use the correct method for the given object type?  Basically - I'm looking for an equivalent of `@RabbitHandler` but is specific for SQS.

Comment: How did you do it with RabbitMQ? `@RabbitListener` would work the same way.

Comment: It looks like it's `@RabbitHandler` on the method level.  I'm seeing some Spring `@Configuration` classes where we are using Spring amqp `QueueBinding` to bind the object type to the queue.

Comment: Yes; that is special logic in spring-rabbit (`@RabbitListener` at the class level and `@RabbitHandler` at the method level). I am not familiar with it, but `@SqsListener` cannot be applied at the class level.

Comment: You could consume `Object` and then do `instanceof` checks in the listener to do the final routing (that's effectively what spring-rabbit does internally).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a class-level `@RabbitListener` with `@RabbitHandler` at the method level.

I am not familiar with it but, looking at the javadocs, `@SqsListener` cannot be applied at the class level (only methods), so it doesn't support method routing by type.

**EDIT**

Unless, or until, the feature is added, you would have to consume `Object` and then add code to your listener to route by type.

Comment: I appreciate the response, Gary.  I tried to go the `Object` route, but either `@SqsListener` or the Spring Cloud AWS library in general, doesn't try to deserialize the JSON to an object before the annotated method is called.  I even tried to create a list of "supported" classes that the `@SqsListener` should support, then iterate over them with Jackson's `ObjectMapper`, but the message always deserializes into the provided type, regardless if the properties match, or not.  `ObjectMapper.readValue()` never throws an exception, even if none of the keys/properties match.

Comment: Spring for RabbitMQ supports two type of message conversion - inferred (where the type to convert to is inferred by the method signature) and native (where the type is determined from the message itself). Since we use the type to select the handler method, you cannot use inferred conversion, only native can be used (catch-22). I don't know if `SqsListener` supports native conversion. Best to find someone more familiar with that project.